# AttributeError in Python code for API pull

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am getting the following error for code I did not write. Not sure what this error is indicating. I've tried adding the 'Series' package but it keeps failing, but I'm not even sure if that's the problem here.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/SocialActivityData/20181030_CE_SocialActivity_API_Call_manual (1).py", line 146, in <module>
    For_df_accountType.append(r.get_values().tolist()[0]['accountType'])

  File "C:\Users\\...\AppData\Local\Temp\20181030_CE_SocialActivity_API_Call_manual (1).py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_values'
```

Code it's referencing:

```
 ### looping through the nested attritutes column to flatten/normalize the column into a somple table with just the required columns

for i, r in df_DimensionsColumns.iterrows():
For_df_index.append(i)
For_df_accountType.append(r.get_values().tolist()[0]['accountType'])

try:
    For_df_message.append(r.get_values().tolist()[0]['content']['message'])
except:
    For_df_message.append('no message available from Sprinklr')
    pass

try:
    For_df_permalink.append(r.get_values().tolist()[0]['permalink'])
except:
    For_df_permalink.append('no permalink available from Sprinklr')
    pass
```

Comment: It _appears_ to be a [pandas series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), and those have no `get_values` method or attribute. Unfortunately, there's not enough code or sample data here to make a [mcve] to tell you more than that

Comment: Maybe `r.values.tolist()`? Or `r.array.tolist()`? Or just ``r.to_list()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not 'add the series package' as it should be contained in what I assume you are using -- [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)

If you check the documentation on `Series`, you'll find that there is no method called `get_values` which is what you're calling here:

```
For_df_accountType.append(r.get_values().tolist()[0]['accountType'])
                          # ^^ Right here
```

It could be that the script or program that you have found was leveraging an earlier version of Pandas, which is causing an issue because you're now using a newer version.

Here is the documentation on `Series`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html

You might try changing `r.get_values().tolist()[0]['accountType']` to something to the effect of `r.array[0]['accountType']`, or perhaps `r.to_list()[0]['accountType']` (per [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html#pandas.Series.to_list))  but I can't guarantee that will work because I have no experience with Pandas.

The documentation is your best friend, really.